# ComboBox array on select event vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox, groupbox

Here is my code to add a combobox array to a groupbox array

```
    Dim gbQuoteProduct(5) As GroupBox
    Dim cmboBoxQuoteProduct(5) As ComboBox
    gbQuoteProduct(n) = New GroupBox

    With gbQuoteProduct(n)
        .Text = ""
        .Location = New Point(10, 5 + n * 70)
        .Width = 300
        .Height = 70
    End With
    pnlQuoteProducts.Controls.Add(gbQuoteProduct(n))

    cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n) = New ComboBox
    With cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n)
        .Items.Add("A")
        .Items.Add("B")
        .Items.Add("C")
        .Items.Add("D")
        .Text = ""
        .Location = New Point(60, 15)
    End With
    gbQuoteProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n))
```

This works fine but I want to add another combobox array to the groupbox array when something is selected from the existing combobox array.

When I try the following:

```
    Private Sub cmboBoxQuoteProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender A
    _ Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles
    _cmboBoxQuoteProduct().SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

I get the error: "Expected "."" where I have the "()" after cmboBoxQuoteProduct

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the form is not going to know about the arrays you build at runtime.  When you create a CBO attach the event using `AddHandler`

Comment: Use withevents then let the framework handle the rest...

Comment: but how do I get it to reload the second combobox if I choose the wrong option from the first combobox (i.e. I click an option in the first combobox and it loads the second combo box, then I select another option from the first combobox and the second combobox stays on the first selection